# how to print the value of map of this type map< map< set< int > ,int >, int> mymap[2]

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator, set

i declared a stl map like this

```
          map< map< set< int > ,int >, int> mymap[2]
```

and i declared iterators like this

```
         set < int > ::iterator it3;
         map< map< set< int > ,int >, int> :: iterator it1;
         map< set< int > ,int > :: iterator it2;
```

and i wrote  some what like this

```
       for(it1=mymap[0].begin();it1!=mymap[0].end();it1++)
    {
            for(it2=(it1->first).begin();it2!=(it1->first).end();it2++)
            {
                  for(it3=(it2->first).begin();it3!=(it2->first).end();it3++)
                  {
                    cout<<*it3<<" "<<it1->second<<endl;
                  }
            }           
    }
}
```

i am getting some weird error can any body help me

Comment: I've found this question non-constructve

Comment: I don't feel inclined to look into this too deeply (wonder why). Just change `iterator` to `const_iterator` see if that helps.

Comment: now its segementation fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems in your code. The most trivial: you're missing a semicolon after the declaration of your map; also, you have an extra brace at the end.

Finally, the keys of a map are `const` values, and when calling `begin()` on a `const` container, what you get is a `const_iterator`, not an `iterator`. Here is how you should fix your program:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

using std::map;
using std::set;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    map< map< set< int > ,int >, int> mymap[2];
    //                                        ^ MISSING SEMICOLON HERE

    map< map< set< int > ,int >, int> :: iterator it1;

    map< set< int > ,int > ::const_iterator it2;
    //                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <== MAP KEYS ARE CONST VALUES!
    set < int > ::const_iterator it3;
    //            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <== MAP KEYS ARE CONST VALUES!

    for(it1=mymap[0].begin();it1!=mymap[0].end();it1++)
    {
        for(it2=(it1->first).begin();it2!=(it1->first).end();it2++)
        {
              for(it3=(it2->first).begin();it3!=(it2->first).end();it3++)
              {
                std::cout<<*it3<<" "<<it1->second<<endl;
              }
        }
    }
    // } <== EXTRA BRACE HERE
}
```

Also notice, that in C++11 you can simplify things by using `auto`, which would have saved your from this kind of troubles:

```
int main()
{
    map< map< set< int > ,int >, int> mymap[2];
    for (auto it1 = mymap[0].begin(); it1 != mymap[0].end(); it1++)
    //   ^^^^
    {
        for (auto it2 = (it1->first).begin(); it2 != (it1->first).end(); it2++)
        //   ^^^^
        {
              for (auto it3=(it2->first).begin(); it3!=(it2->first).end(); it3++)
              //   ^^^^
              {
                  std::cout<<*it3<<" "<<it1->second<<endl;
              }
        }
    }
}
```

Range-based `for` loops make this even simpler:

```
int main()
{
    map< map< set< int >, int >, int> mymap[2];
    for (auto const& m : mymap[0])
    {
        for (auto const& s : m.first)
        {
            for (auto const& e : s.first)
            {
                std::cout << e << " " << m.second << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry sir semicolons wantedly i did not keep in the question

Comment: @rafanadal: No problem, that happens

Answer (score -2):

<int name="ModChaSendBKColor" value="-4003595"/>